# What does this error when I'm trying to run an example in Apache Mahout?

Tags: hadoop, config, mahout

I configured and ran examples with mahout but I get the following error :

> hadoop binary is not in PATH,HADOOP_HOME/bin,HADOOP_PREFIX/bin,
>   running locally Error occurred during initialization of VM

In my, `.bashrc`, I defined the following aliases :

> JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,MAHOUT_CONF_DIR,HADOOP_HOME

I already have configured this in `/etc/bash.bashrc` :

- `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386`
- `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`
- `export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/hadoop-0.20.2`
- `export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin`
- `export MAHOUT_HOME=/home/user/mahout/trunk`
- `export classpath=$classpath:$MAHOUT_HOME/src/conf`
- `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/user/hadoop-0.20.2/conf`
- `export classpath=$classpath:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`

However,  I have the following error :

`MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, so we don't add HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath. Error: Could not find or load main class classpath MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, running locally Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

Comment: Which version of Mahout are you using? Does this everything that mahout script printed?

Comment: I am using Mahout version 0.8-SNAPSHOT. Hadooop-0.20.0, I installed and compiled as link https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/buildingmahout.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Mahout or Hadoop, but your shell. You appear to be using `HADOOP_HOME` instead of `$HADOOP_HOME` in your path expression somewhere, for example.

Comment: please, give full example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try: unset MAHOUT_LOCAL